# What is the physical significance of Dipole moment?

Tags: electrostatics, electricity, dipole, dipole-moment

What does dipole moment physically signify? I know it is the product of 2 charges and distance between them. Like momentum is the product of mass and velocity, but physically it shows the quantity of motion the larger the momentum the harder it would be to stop a moving body. I know this question has been asked, but no has answered its physical significance.

Comment: Dipole moment is not the product of two charges and the distance between them. It contains just one charge and the other charge is just of opposite sign and same magnitude.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the dipole moment is a vector which is the product of the charge magnitude and the displacement vector pointing from the negative to the positive charge. An electric dipole consists of 2 equal magnitude, opposite-signed charges.

The physical significance is it gives a measure of the polarity/polarization of a net neutral system. If the dipole moment is small, either the charges are small or the separation is small. The electric field due to the polarization will be small.  If the polarization is large (large charges/large separation), the electric field will be distinctly non-monopole.

The dipole moment also measures the tendency of a dipole to align with an external electric field. The moment will be parallel to the local field, and weak dipoles are easily twisted out of alignment by external work such as mechanical vibration or thermal effects.

Answer (score 1):

A simple conceptual picture is that the dipole moment is a kind of average quantity which lets you describe the resultant torque from an external field.

For example, for two charges, $q$ and $-q$, the dipole moment $\boldsymbol{d}$

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{d} = q\boldsymbol{r}
\end{align}

where $\boldsymbol{r}$ is the displacement vector from one charge to the other, giving a resultant torque, $\boldsymbol{\tau}$,

\begin{align}
\boldsymbol{\tau} = \boldsymbol{d} \times \boldsymbol{E}
\end{align}

This can be generalised to a general case with a charge distribution.

A second, alternative way of thinking of the dipole moment is that it's the next term in an expansion of a general charge distribution's coulomb potential i.e. a multipole expansion.

That is, to zeroth-order the potential is described by its total charge, to first order you need to include its dipole moment, to second-order you need the quadrupole moment, etc.  In this sense, the dipole moment is the next simplest piece of information (after the total charge) required to approximately describe a generalised charge distribution.

At least, this level of explanation is sufficient for me.  Perhaps others can expand upon this if I've missed out something critical or included something misleading...

I hope this helps.